# Can we change the order of precedence between back-ticks and dollar signs for SE Markup language and the MathJax plug-in?

Tags: bug, mathjax

I sometimes attempt to use $\mathcal{MathJax}$ to write string-literals wrapped in quotes.

I expected the rendered result to look like this:

> [image: a pretty set of strings]

Instead the result was this:

> [image: picture of stuff which is half referred in mono-spaced fixed width teletype font and the other half is renders as MathJax stuff]

For example, we might have the following markdown for a stack exchange posting:

```
Let $A$ be the set $\{ ``\mathtt{CAT}", ``\mathtt{CONCAT}", ``\mathtt{CONCATENATE}" \}$
```

The problem is that...

> - Stack Exchange uses back-ticks to render text in a `mono-spaced` `teletype` `font`
> - $\mathcal{MathJax}$ and $\LaTeX$ use exactly two consecutive back-ticks to render a left-double quote `“`. ASCII straight double quotation marks are always treated as right-quotation mark.

There are various solutions.

I was hoping that the order of precedence would be:

1. Triple back-tick
2. Dollar signs for $\mathcal{MathJax}$

Another alternative is that a double back-tick with nothing in-between the ticks is treated as a special token by the tokenizer, parser, or compiler for stack exchange mark-up language.

---

Double back-tick with nothing in-between the two ticks could be rendered as the Unicode character left-double quote `“`. People usually write somthing in-between back-ticks, such as:

```
`hello world`
```

If there are backticks with nothing in-between it could be rendered as a double left quote

```
``
```

Answer (score 0):

LGTM:

[image]